# Dataframe object is not callable in python

Tags: python, pandas

So I have been following this video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6tQhoUuQrOw 13:48 to get a feel of machine learning and there seems to be a problem with what I think is syntax changes from python2.7 to python3

I have seen similar problems but couldn't understand the cause of the problem, I tried removing one of data (from len(data(data.FTR == 'H')) but it returns the length of all the rows.

```
#Data Exploring
#what is the win rate for the home team

n_matches = data.shape[0]

n_features = data.shape[1] - 1

n_homewin = len(data(data.FTR == 'H')) # this part is giving error

win_rate = (float(n_homewin) / (n_matches)) * 100

print("Total number of matches : {}".format(n_matches))
print("Number of features : {}".format(n_features))
print("Number of matches won by home team : {}".format(n_homewin))
print("percent of home team : {:.2f}%".format(win_rate))




TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-18-b49d4b31ffa3> in <module>
      6 n_features = data.shape[1] - 1
      7 
----> 8 n_homewin = len(data(data.FTR == 'H'))
      9 
     10 win_rate = (float(n_homewin) / (n_matches)) * 100

TypeError: 'DataFrame' object is not callable
```

Comment: May be `len(data[data.FTR == 'H'])` ?

Comment: Thank you so much, yes it works, can you explain why or what is the concept? @harvpan

Comment: Checkout my answer. Let me know if that clears out.

Answer (score 0):

This will also do:

```
   _, n_homewin = np.shape(np.where(data.FTR == 'H'))
```

Answer (score 0):

`data` is a pandas [DataFrame](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html) and it is not callable. Meaning, you cannot do data() .

You want to filter out information based on one column `FTR`. So you need data[..] where `[]` is used for data query.